NTLM v2 miss ['Authorization']
I’m having a problem with NTLM v2 connection. After some changes at my workplace, my code stopped working. I checked the NTLM with the [‘Authorization’] header, but since the Active Directory changes, the [‘Authorization’] header is missing in my dump.
To solve this, I modified the registry key:
\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa\MSV1_0\NtlmMinClientSec
setting the value to 20000000 instead of 80000. However, my system settings update every hour, and the system administrators cannot modify them permanently.
Is it possible to get the [‘Authorization’] header with NTLM v2 without requiring a 128-bit session security?
Here is my code in Symfony:
`public static function connexionWindows()
{
$browser = self::getBrowser();
if ($browser['platform'] != "windows" or ($browser['name'] != 'Google Chrome' and $browser['name'] != 'Internet Explorer')) {
    return false;
}

$headers = apache_request_headers(); // Retrieve client headers
dump($headers);

if (@$_SERVER['HTTP_VIA'] != NULL) { // Check if a proxy is used: NTLM authentication cannot pass through a proxy
    return false;
} elseif (!isset($headers['Authorization'])) { // If the Authorization header is missing
    header("HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized"); // Send the authentication mode to the client
    header("Connection: Keep-Alive");
    header("WWW-Authenticate: Negotiate");
    header("WWW-Authenticate: NTLM"); // In our case, NTLM
    exit;
}

Example of dump($headers) before the update:
"Host" => "XXXXXX" "Connection" => "keep-alive" "Cache-Control" => "max-age=0" "Authorization" => "NTLM TlRMTXXXXXXXX" "sec-ch-ua" => "\"Not/A)Brand\";v=\"8\", \"Chromium\";v=\"126\", \"Microsoft Edge\";v=\"126\"" "sec-ch-ua-mobile" => "?0"
Example of dump($headers) after the update:
"Host" => "XXXXXX" "Connection" => "keep-alive" "Cache-Control" => "max-age=0" "sec-ch-ua" => "\"Not/A)Brand\""
can you help me please ?
I can't find any similar problem
